# mongo db installation showing storage engine error

Tags: mongodb

I just installed monodb(version 3.2) at my windows machine. I created /data/db directory also. when i give the command "mongod" to start it, it shows the following error

```
 exception in initAndListen: 28663 Cannot start server. The default storage engine 'wiredTiger' is not available with this build of mongod. Please specify a different storage engine explicitly, e.g. --storageEngine=mmapv1., terminating
```

previously I installed version 3.0 but no error like that.
Can any body help me with this?

Comment: Got the same problem today ..after installation of mongo db ..

Answer (score 3):

In there site they are saying that the default storage engine is "wiredTiger" but it has been also said that wired tiger does not work in 32 bit environment. so I wrote in my command line

```
mongod.exe --storageEngine=mmapv1
```

to switch to mmapv1(the default storage engine og 3.0 version) and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
mongod --storageEngine=mmapv1 --dbpath "Your Path"
```

For more details Please go through [MongoDb Tutorial](https://technicalforum.wordpress.com/2016/12/10/mongodb-tutorial-part1/)